# Adding a property to UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to create a UITableView within a UIViewController. I want to create some custom UITableViewCell's as well. However I'm having some difficulty trying to figure out how I can add a UILabel property to the UITableViewCell. I get the following error when I run the code... "Property '_label1' not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell'" Any help would be appreciated.

The .h

```
@interface gideViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,     UITableViewDataSource> {
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *data;
```

The .m

```
@synthesize label1 = _label1;
@synthesize data = _data;
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self._data count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell     alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefaultreuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

//*********** This is where I get the compiler error ... "Property '_label1' not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell'"///
cell._label1.text = [self._data
                       objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.data = [[NSArray alloc]
                 initWithObjects:@"ABC",
                 @"DEF",
                 @"XYZ",
                 @"JKY", nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you create your custom table view cell? Did you subclass it? If you did subcalls it and named your subclass MyTableViewCell then change the line

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

to

```
MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

And register MyTableViewCell with the cell identifier that you want to use here. 
You may want to use another identifier for those type of cells anyway.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyTableCell";
```

Another option is adding `label1` as subview (not property!!!) to each cell upon creation.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    // Caution! If you want this line to be executed, then you MUST not register the cell identifier with any cell's class. Because if you register it then the dequeue method will automatically create an object of that class and return it. 
    // Plus you must not create this cell in IB using storyboard because then it is atuomatically registered. (Or do it properly and completely in IB. But then this code sniplet would be redundant) 
    cell = [[UITableViewCell     alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefaultreuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];  // I think you could use initWithFrame too for layouting purposes
    [cell.contentview addSubview:label1];
    lable1.tag = 99;   // this is to fetch the label on re-use
    // here you may layout the label, set colors etc.
}
// here you can fetch the label using the tag as identifier and then set its text value
```

There are more ways of implementing that, of course. However, subclassing is probably the smarter option.